# Every point has path connected neighborhood, but the entire topological space is not locally path connected

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

$X$ is a topological space, and for each point $x\in X$, it has a path connected neighborhood. Can $X$ be not locally path connected?

I think this is possible since for locally path connected, we require that for any neighborhood $U$ of $x\in X$ should contain a path connected neighborhood $V$, no matter how "small" the $U$ is.

However, if just let every point has a path connected neighborhood $V$, it's possible that there exists a neighborhood of $x$, let's say $U$, such that $U\subset V$, but $U$ doesn't contain any locally path connected neighborhood of $x$

I can't find an example. Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: Well, how about if $X$ itself is path-connected?  Do you know an example of a path-connected space that is not locally path-connected

Comment: Yes, I got it, thanks!